# How do you Require Login for Media Files in Django

Tags: django, apache, authentication, static, media

I'm serving "sensitive" information in downloadable PDF's and Spreadsheets within a user registration section of a site.

Is there a way to allow the django authentication to secure this media **without** serving it (and not have to manually login using basic auth)?

I'm guessing theres (fingers crossed) *not* a way to do it with the psuedo code below, but it helps better illustrate the end goal.

```
#urls.py
(r'^protected_media/(?P<filename>.*)$', 'protected_media')

#views.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def protected_media(request, filename):
    # @login_required bounces you out to the login url
    # if logged in, serve "filename" from Apache
```

Comment: could you add the line to in `protected_media` to actually serve the file?

Comment: See [`django-downloadview`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-downloadview)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me that the method you outlined in your code should work.  It's really no different than any other protected resource:  your views can serve files from disks, records from databases, rendered templates or anything.  Just as the login_required decorator prevents unauthorized access to other views, it will prevent such access to your view serving protected media.

Am I missing something from your question here?  Please clarify if that's the case.

EDIT:  With regard to the django doc link in your comment: that's the method for simply serving any request file from a particular directory.  So, in that example URLS like `/site_media/foo.jpg`, `/site_media/somefolder/bar.jpg` will automatically look for files `foo.jpg` and `somefolder/bar.jpg` under `document_root`.  Basically, every thing under `document_root` will be publicly available.  That's obviously insecure.  So you avoid that with your method.

It's also considered inefficient because django is just adding a lot of unnecessary overhead when all you need is something like Apache to take a URL request and map it to a file on the hard drive.  (You don't need django sessions, request processing, etc.)

In your case, this may not be such a big concern.  First, you've secured the view.  Second, it depends on your usage patterns.  How many requests do you anticipate for these files?  You're only using django for authentication -- does that justify other overhead?  If not, you can look into serving those files with Apache and using an authentication provider.  For more on this, see the `mod_wsgi` documentation:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms

  - see the section "Apache Authentication Provider" and search for django

There are similar mechanisms available under `mod_python` I believe.  (Update: just noticed the other answer.  Please see Andre's answer for the `mod_python` method.)

EDIT 2:  With regard to the code for serving a file, please see this snippet:

- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/

The `send_file` method uses a FileWrapper which is good for sending large static files back (it doesn't read the entire file into memory).  You would need to change the `content_type` depending on the type of file you're sending (pdf, jpg, etc).

Comment: Hey Ars, I should have clarified that I'm trying to mediate the following concern from the django docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#the-big-fat-disclaimer

If this line of psuedo-code is valid, how do you accomplish it?
# if logged in, serve "filename" from Apache

Thanks!-Tom

Answer (score 5):

Read this [Django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2131) for more info. Start at the bottom to save yourself some time. Looks like it just missed getting into Django 1.2, and I assume also isn't in 1.3.

For Nginx, I found this [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/491/) that takes advantage of the X-Accel-Redirect header, but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you want to restrict access to files that are not being served by Django, for example, with an Apache server?

What you would then require is some way for this Apache server to use Django as an authentication source.

This [django snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/62/) describes such a method. It creates an access handler in Django which is used by Apache when a request for a static file comes in that needs to be protected:

```
<Location "/protected/location">
            PythonPath "['/path/to/proj/'] + sys.path"  
            PythonOption DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myproj.settings
        PythonOption DjangoPermissionName '<permission.codename>'
        PythonAccessHandler my_proj.modpython #this should point to accesshandler
            SetHandler None
</Location>
```

Hope this helps, the snippet was posted a while ago, so things might have changed between Django versions :)

Answer (score 3):

More efficient serving of static files through Django is being looked at currently as part of Google SOC project. For WSGI this will use wsgi.file_wrapper extensions for WSGI if available, as it is for mod_wsgi, and req.sendfile() if using mod_python. It will also support returning of headers such as 'Location', 'X-Accel-Redirect' and others, which different web hosting mechanisms and proxy front ends accept as a means of serving up static files where location is defined by a backend web application, which isn't as effecient as front end for serving static files.

I am not sure if there is a project page for this in Django wiki somewhere or not, but the code changes are being committed into the branches/soc2009/http-wsgi-improvements branch of Django source code repository.

You needn't strictly wait for that stuff. It is just putting a clean and portable interface in place across the different mechanisms. If using nginx as front end in front of Apache/mod_wsgi, you could use X-Accel-Redirect now. If using Apache/mod_wsgi 3.0 and daemon mode, you could use Location now, but do need to ensure you set up Apache correct. Alternatively, you could implement your own WSGI middleware wrapper around the Django application which looks for some response header of your own to indicate file to be returned and which uses wsgi.file_wrapper to return that instead of actual response returned from Django.

BTW, the authentication hook mechanisms listed for both mod_python and mod_wsgi by others would use HTTP basic authentication, which isn't what you wanted. This is presuming you want files to be protected by Django form based login mechanism using cookies and backend sessions.