# Django: Nginx with gunicorn media files protection

Tags: django, nginx

Please do not downvote as this question does not have tried code. I am new to programming.

So far have a built a big project on local machine. It will automate business workings.
However now issue is, while deploying the app to server, Media files are not protected. I mean how to allow media files to be downloaded by logged in users only.
As of now anyone with a link can download the file.

In short question is:

```
How to allow media files (user uploaded files) to be downloaded only by logged in users in NGINX?
```

Google is not of much help here, need a working example with code.
The question is not duplication of [How do you Require Login for Media Files in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114559)
I have asked for a working example. If someone can give a working example of django-sendfile that will be great too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Require Login for Media Files in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114559/how-do-you-require-login-for-media-files-in-django)

Comment: Could be but as I said have no coded solution. Please provide a coded solution.

Comment: If you look at the first answer to the duplicate it has a link to a snippet that has the code you need.

Comment: That does not solve the issue. Need a solution showing, what needs to be configured at NGINX setting, Media link and Django view.